# How to send GET request in Retrofit ?(It gives error)

Tags: retrofit

I'm new at Retofit. I try to request the server but my app is craching. So, I dont know what's the problem. Below you can see my code:

```
  if(retrofit==null){
    retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Base_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build())
           .build();
 }

return retrofit;

@GET("api.php")
Call<List<MyModel>> getLikersPost(@Field("id") String id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use @Field parameter with @GET request. Instead you must use @Query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Now my code worked:
@GET("api.php")
Call> getLikersPost(@Query("id") String id);

Comment: if the first answer helped you please choose is as the right answer.

Comment: @CoolSolutions yes firs answer helped me. I  choose it as the right answer. Thanks to say it.